# Titanium Studio Installation error

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to install titanium studio in windows 7 . But i am stuck as it is giving me an error : Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file :CRC error . Please have a look at the screenshot .

[image]

Any help would be appreciated .

PS: windows is 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to install Node.js from [the official website](https://nodejs.org/). I had the exact same issue and this solved my problem.

Comment: Althought it is written in the documentation that installer will itself download and install the node.js if it is not present. But you have to install it before installing studio . Thanks it worked for me too !!!